# Repeat code for whole array

Tags: ios, iphone, arrays, swift

I am using some Facebook IDs in my app, and I have an array of serveral ID's, the array can be 10 numbers but can also be 500 numbers..
Right now the numbers are displayed in a tableview, and I want all the results there too, so they need to be in an array.

```
let profileUrl = NSURL(string:"http://www.facebook.com/" + newArray[0])!
let task = NSURLSession.sharedSession().dataTaskWithURL(profileUrl) { 
    (data, response, error) -> Void in
    // Will happen when task completes
    if let urlContent = data {
        let webContent = NSString(data: urlContent, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), 
            { () -> Void in
            let websiteArray = webContent!.componentsSeparatedByString("pageTitle\">")
            //print(websiteArray[1])
            let secondArray = websiteArray[1].componentsSeparatedByString("</title>")
            print(secondArray[0])
            })
    }
}
```

this code takes the first number of the array, goes to facebook.com/[the actual number], and then downloads the data and splits the data into pieces, so that the data that I want it in the secondArray[0]. I want to do this for every number of the array, take the result data and put it back into an array. I have no idea how to do this because you don't know how much numbers there are gonna be etc, does someone has a good solution for this?

Any help would be appreciated, really!

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have several problems here, and you should take them one at at a time to build up to your solution.

First, forget the table for the moment. Don't worry at all about how you're going to display these results. Just focus on getting the results in a simple form, and then you'll go back and convert that simple form into something easy to display, and then you'll display it.

So first, we want this in a simple form. That's a little bit complicated because it's all asynchronous. But that's not too hard to fix.

```
func fetchTitle(identifier: String, completion: (title: String) -> Void) {
    let profileUrl = NSURL(string:"http://www.facebook.com/" + identifier)!
    let task = NSURLSession.sharedSession().dataTaskWithURL(profileUrl) {
        (data, response, error) -> Void in
        if let urlContent = data {
            let webContent = NSString(data: urlContent, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)
            let websiteArray = webContent!.componentsSeparatedByString("pageTitle\">")
            let secondArray = websiteArray[1].componentsSeparatedByString("</title>")
            let title = secondArray[0]
            completion(title: title)
        }
    }
    task.resume()
}
```

Now this is still pretty bad code because it doesn't handle errors at all, but it's a starting point, and the most important parts are here. A function that takes a string, and when it's done fetching things, calls some completion handler.

(Regarding error handling, note how many places this code would crash if it were returned surprising data. Maybe the data you get isn't a proper string. Maybe it's not formatted like you think it is. Every time you use `!` or subscript an array, you run the risk of crashing. Try to minimize those.)

So you might then wrap it up in something like:

```
var titles = [String]()
let identifiers = ["1","2","3"]
let queue = dispatch_queue_create("titles", DISPATCH_QUEUE_SERIAL)

dispatch_apply(identifiers.count, queue) { index in
    let identifier = identifiers[index]
    fetchTitle(identifier) { title in
        dispatch_async(queue) {
            titles.append(title)
        }
    }
}
```

This is just code to get you on the right track and start studying the right things. It certainly would need work to be production quality (particularly to handle errors).

Once you have something that returns your titles correctly, you should be able to write a program that does nothing but take a list of identifiers and prints out the list of titles. Then you can add code to integrate that list into your tableview. Keep the parts separate. The titles are the Model. The table is the View. Read up on the Model-View-Controller paradigm, and you'll be in good shape.

Comment: Hi! I don't know how I could thank you, this is amazing! Really big thanks! But I do have a little question, when I print the titles array, or try to put it into a table, I doesn't show anything, I think this is because it does this immediately and it takes a little while to get all the titles from facebook, how could I make it delay till everything is loaded?

Comment: The dispatch_apply won't return until everything has completed. But that could take awhile. You can't wait for that on the main queue. You'll need to put it all on a background queue and signal the main queue to redraw the table when it's done. Probably the best place to start (after going through all of Apple's Getting Started guides, especially the ones about table views(, is the Concurrency Programming Guide https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/General/Conceptual/ConcurrencyProgrammingGuide/Introduction/Introduction.html.

Answer (score 0):

To repeat code for whole `array` put your code in a loop and run that loop from 0 to `array.count-1`
You don't need to know how many items there will be an array. You can just get the count at run time `array.count` here `array` is your array.

I hope this is what you wanted to know, your question doesn't make much sense though.

Comment: Thanks! This repeats the code, but I need the result in an array too, any idea how I would do that? and also, each time the code is ran again and let's say the second number of the array is up, then the code needs to be changed, any idea?

Comment: Please search for tutorials and learn to code, thats the best way.